# Blur all except hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a simple static webpage, and wanted to do this neat little effect but ran into a problem.

What I want to do: *Cover the screen with a photo. When a "invisible" container centered on the screen is hovered, blur background except the container.*

I have 2 layers (div), 'bg' and 'overlay'. 'bg' contains an image that will fill the screen, while 'overlay' is *width/height 600px/450px* container at the center. If I only input 'overlay's size and position it will just be a see through container and it will look blurred when 'background' is blurred.

I could use the same photo as background in 'overlay', so that 'overlay' isn't see through, just a photo on top of the background. Problem here is that when i use `background-size: cover` on the 'bg', the overlay background photo does not match the 'bg' background photo when zoomed in/out (not responsive).

Any ideas how I can solve this?

**Note:** `background-size: cover` line 23 is slashed out

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmqrbN)

```css
:root {
  --url: url(https://i.imgur.com/2N39vV4.jpg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--url);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  //background-size: cover;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 37.5vw;
  height: 59.36675461741425vh;
  background: var(--url);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

.overlay:hover~.bg {
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
}

.overlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the `.bg` a pseudo element (the `::before`) that covers the screen, and has the same image, with the same position. Use [`clip-path()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to cut a hole in the middle. When the overlay is hovered blur the `::before`

```css
:root {
  --url: url(https://loremflickr.com/800/600);
  --c-width: 37.5vw;
  --c-height: 59.36675461741425vh;
  --c-left: calc(50% - var(--c-width) / 2);
  --c-right: calc(50% + var(--c-width) / 2);
  --c-top: calc(50% - var(--c-height) / 2);
  --c-bottom: calc(50% + var(--c-height) / 2);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg, .bg::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--url) fixed no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg::before {
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%, 
    0% 100%, 
    var(--c-left) 100%, 
    var(--c-left) var(--c-top), 
    var(--c-right) var(--c-top), 
    var(--c-right) var(--c-bottom), 
    var(--c-left) var(--c-bottom), 
    var(--c-left) 100%, 
    100% 100%, 
    100% 0%
  );
  transition: filter 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  content: '';
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--c-top);
  left: var(--c-left);
  width: var(--c-width);
  height: var(--c-height);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
}

.overlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.overlay:hover + .bg::before {
  filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Aha did not know about clip-path.
That's clever. Thank you!